# How to find all the matched patterns in a variable and writing them to output and a newline character every of matched string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string variable as

```
$variable
```

and I have a pattern as like:

```
/<OPTION [^>]*>\D*([^<]+)/g
```

How can I print all the matched strings inside that variable and writing to console a newline character - \n after every matched string with Perl?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the use of TreeBuilder to parse HTML. You will gain performance if use [XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.12/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm) or the [look_down()](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.2/lib/HTML/Element.pm) function.

By the way:

```
my @arr = $variable =~ /<OPTION [^>]*>D*([^<]+)/g;
for(0 .. @arr - 1) {
    print $arr[$_] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a module for processing HTML data. If you insist on doing it The Wrong Way:

```
print join("\n", $variable =~ /<OPTION [^>]*>\D*([^<]+)/g), "\n";
```